# Use output from one aggregation pipeline stage in condition for the next stage

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Is it possible to use a field from an aggregation stage to filter data in a future stage?

I have this query where I do a match and then a lookup.  I'm using mongodb 3.4 so I can't filter the lookup with a condition.  What I would like to do is do a do a match or a project with a filter after the lookup so that I can further filter the documents from the classes collection.

In this scenario the fist collection has a student ID, so the $lookup matches on student ID in the classes collection.  The issue is that there can be multiple classes for a single studentID and the $lookup pulls back all of them.  I want to use data from the match to further filter so I can pull back a single class for each student.

```
    collection.aggregate([
        {$match: {"field1": "value"}},
        {
            $lookup: {
               from: "classes",
               localField: "studentId",
               foreignField: "student._id",
               as: "classes"
            }
        },
        //filter with a match
        {
            $match: {
                "classes.field1": "$field1value", //$field1value is a field from the first collection
            }
        }
        //or filter with project and condition
        { 
            $project: {
                class: {
                    filter: {
                        input: "classes",
                        as: "class",
                        cond: {$eq: ['$$class.field1', "$classes.field1value"]}
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ])
```

Comment: please provide sazmple data and expected output

Answer (score 0):

Use lookup with `pipeline`. The following query will work:

```
collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { "field1": "value" } },
  { $lookup: {
    from: "classes",
    let: [studentId: "$studentId", field1value: "$field1value"],
    pipeline: [{ $match: {
      $expr: { 
        $and: [
          { $eq: ["$_id", "$$studentId"] },
          { $eq: ["$field1", "$$field1value"] },
        ]
      },
    } }],
    as: "classes",
  } }
]);
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: Does pipeline work with mongodb 3.4 or does it require a later version?

Comment: It requires a later version. It was introduced in 3.6